# How do you undo a rollback (rollforward?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and by mistake I did a rollback. Is there anyway to do a rollforward?

also is there a command to check out which migrations i have no migrated yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rake db:migrate
```

should rerun everything

In order to see which is the last migration you have run, you can check the `schema_migrations` table inside your database. The last row is generally the last run migration.

Comment: Thanks it worked! (have to wait 10 mins before i can mark that as correct)

Comment: No problem, I've added the answer to the second question aswell :)